# Displaying Age to datatables laravel

Tags: laravel, datatables

i Have a function to showing `Age` on Model

This Model like this :

```php
public function getAgeAttribute()
{
    return Carbon::parse($this->attributes['tanggal_lahir'])->age;
}
```

and i parsing data on `view` ( without datatable) like

```php
$users->age
```

but on datatable , not showing this data , just only `Age` is not showing

My Controller

```php
public function indexDataTables_nonpns()
{

    $users = User::with('master_agama','master_unit_kerja')->whereNotIn('nama',['admin'])->whereNotIn('roles_id',['2'])->get();


    return Datatables::of($users)->addIndexColumn()
    ->addColumn('Nama', function ($users) {
        return '<a href="project/non_pns/'.$users->id.'">'.$users->nama.'</a>';
    })

    ->rawColumns(['Nama' => 'Nama'])
    ->make(true);

}
```

My `View`

```html
@push('scripts')
  <script>
    $(function() {
        $('#table').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            responsive: true,
            ajax: '{!! route('d_non_pns') !!}',
            columns: [
                { data: 'DT_RowIndex', name: 'DT_RowIndex', orderable: false,searchable: false},
                { data: 'Nama', name: 'Nama'},
                { data: 'NIK', name: 'NIK'},
                { data: 'jenis_kelamin', name: 'jenis_kelamin'},
                { data: 'tempat_lahir', name: 'tempat_lahir'},
                { data: 'tanggal_lahir', name: 'tanggal_lahir'},
                { data: 'age', name: 'age'}, // i change this users.age ,but its didnt work
                { data: 'pendidikan', name: 'pendidikan'},
                { data: 'alamat', name: 'alamat'},
                { data: 'master_agama.agama', name: 'master_agama.agama'},
                { data: 'master_unit_kerja.unit_kerja', name: 'master_unit_kerja.unit_kerja'},

            ],
        });
    })
</script>
@endpush
```

someone can correct my fault ?

Comment: try with adding `protected $appends = ['age'];` in model.

Comment: can you ```dd``` $user varibale and post the question